# Jenkins pipeline job start by hook by release

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucked repo, and I want to satrt my Jenkins pipeline job only afrer commit with tag like **"release-1.0.*"**
So, I seted my job up with pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Prepare') {
            when { 
                tag "release*" 
            }
            steps {
                git branch: 'tag1', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:m*********ny/tests.git'
            }
        }
        stage ('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: "JenkinsSrv", transfers: [sshTransfer(execCommand: 'pwd')])])
            }
        }
    }
    post ('POST BUILD'){
        always {
            echo 'This is post action!!!'
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I turned on **Bitbucked webhook plugin**, than my repo notify Jenkins about new changes.
But my solution doesn't work. Help me resolve this case.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8RGD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official documentation for a Jenkins [pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when), the option you are looking for is the *changelog* condition inside the when directive. For example:

```
when { changelog 'release*' }
```

Comment: thanks! Please give me a hint or best practice solution, what I should do when I need to deploy code from 4 repo(bitbucked) only if into 4 repo made commits with tags "release"